# Pasar variable de JavaScript a Clase Java de un select

Tags: javascript, java, html

Estoy tratando de pasar la variable o el texto seleccionado de un SELECT - OPTION de un JSP a una clase java conexión o cualquier clase, lo ideal que esta variable sea global para que viaje por todas las clases utilizadas.

Este es mi JSP con la parte de JavaScript donde obtengo el texto de lo seleccionado.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowSelected()
{
    /* Para obtener el texto */
    var combo = document.getElementById("base");
    var selected  = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text = <%=VARIABLE.getBD() %>;
}
</script>
```

```html
 <select class="select100" name="cbobd"  id="base"  onchange="ShowSelected()">
     <option>--SELECCIONE--</option>
     <option>BASE1</option>
     <option>BASE2</option>
 </select>
```

Cabe recalcar que esta variable es obtenida de la clase conexiones donde esta los constructores *get* y *set*.

```
public class conexiones {
    public String BD;

    public String getBD() {
        return BD;
    }

    public void setBD(String BD) {
        this.BD = BD;
    }
```

Pero cuando selecciono la opción en el *select* me remplaza con el texto "NULL" y hasta el momento no puedo obtener cual es el problema, quisiera saber si esta lógica es la correcta o me esta faltando algo en la función **ShowSelected**  al obtener el texto indicado.

Comment: Prueba con :  "<%=VARIABLE.getBD() %>" comillas dobles en esta parte

Comment: coloque las comillas pero aun asi,cuando selecciono la opcion del select se cambia a null

Comment: Los selects siempre deben llevar un atributo value con el valor